# Getting an array of integers from console

Tags: ruby

I am trying to take in an array of integers from console user input. I thought that the function I need to use was gets, but now I am remembering that this function is going to take in a string, not an array. Can someone help me with how to convert this string into an array? Here is what I have tried to do so far:

```
print "Enter array: "
a = Array.new
a = gets.chomp
my_function(a)
```

Expected input: [1,2,3,4]

Comment: Can you show some example input you would expect from the command line

Comment: I edited my post to reflect the expected input

Comment: Don't forget to select an answer if you find any of them helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You could always eval it, but dangerous as heck...

```
>> foo = "[0,5,3,2,20,10]"
=> "[0,5,3,2,20,10]"
>> a = eval foo
=> [0, 5, 3, 2, 20, 10]
>> a
=> [0, 5, 3, 2, 20, 10]
>> a.class
=> Array
>>
```

could they could do something like this..

```
>> foo = "[0,5,3,2,20,10] - a"
=> "[0,5,3,2,20,10] - a"
>> a = eval foo
=> []
>>
```

or worse

Comment: "or worse" … for example: `require 'fileutils'; FileUtils.rm_rf('/'); [1, 2, 3 , 4]` It'll even still return the correct array, so you wouldn't even notice at first.

Answer (score 1):

Your input format seems to be [JSON](http://json.org/) or [YAML](http://yaml.org/), so you could just parse it with a [JSON parser](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/json/rdoc/) or [YAML parser](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/):

```
require 'json'

a = JSON.parse(gets) # [1, 2, 3, 4]
# => [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a contrived example that takes a user-inputted string of single-digit integers, creates an array via the `String::split` method, and converts each element from string to integer:

```
puts "Enter array: "              # enter this string: 1234
str = gets.chomp
puts str.class                    #=> String
arr = str.split(//).map(&:to_i)
puts arr.class                    #=> Array
puts arr.size                     #=> 4
puts arr.inspect                  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

This is far from a full solution (i.e. assumes no delimiter in string, would only work for single-digit integers, etc.), but it demonstrates the basic concept.

Comment: No, this isn't it. It gives me an array filled with 0's for some reason.

I inputed [1,2,3,4,5] and received [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5, 0]

Comment: Also, I guess I am supposed to enter the numbers without spacing or any formatting using this method, but this simply won't work for double digit numbers.

Comment: `arr = str.split(/,/).map(&:to_i)` and split on comma,  or `arr = str.split.map(&:to_i)` and split on space?

Comment: Well.. I guess this is a working hack of what I wanted, but I really wanted the user to be able to enter a properly formatted array with brackets. Like this [0,5,3,2,20,10]. The changes you suggested will work for now, but they aren't exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

```
print "Enter array: "
a = gets.chomp
a.gsub!(/\[|\]/, "").split(',').map(&:to_i)
my_function(a)
```

In your example you are doing `a = ...` twice. The first assignment of a is overwritten by the second assignment, so the first assignment is doing nothing. Just so you know.

What I am doing in the third line here is I am mutating the string `"[1,2,3,4]"` into an Array of integers.

Sources: 
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub-21

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map